# HttpError 401 "Login Required" while using Calendar v3 api python to insert event

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I am using python and appengine to create an application that uses Google Calendar API (V3).

I am able to list events, from multiple calendars etc. However, I am running into problems when trying to insert an event into a calendar.

If I use get() in my handler, everything works fine (ie. event is inserted properly. However, if I use a form and post() to insert the event (in the same calendar) it fails with the following message

---

```
<HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/.../events?alt=json returned "Login Required">

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
   return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/.../oauth2client/appengine.py", line 469, in check_oauth
return method(request_handler, *args, **kwargs)

File "/base/data/home/apps/...", line 99, in post
request = service.events().insert(calendarId='MyCalendarId', body=event).execute()

File "/base/data/home/apps/.../apiclient/http.py", line 678, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)

HttpError: <HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/.../events?alt=json returned "Login Required">
```

---

Simplified versions of functions get() and post() are below:

```
class AddEvent(webapp2.RequestHandler):
@decorator.oauth_required
def post(self):
    if decorator.has_credentials():          
        #event_name = self.request.get('event-name')
        event = {  
         'summary': self.request.get('summary'),  
         'location': self.request.get('place'),  
         'status' : self.request.get('status'),
         'start': {    
                   'dateTime': '2013-05-11T10:00:00.000-07:00'  ,
                   'timeZone': 'America/New_York'
                   },  
         'end': {    
                 'dateTime': '2013-05-11T10:25:00.000-07:00',
                 'timeZone': 'America/New_York'  
                 },  
        }

        request = service.events().insert(calendarId='MyCalendarId', body=event).execute()

    else:
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps({'error': 'No credentials'}))

    page = 'main'
    template_values = {
      'url': url,
      'url_linktext': url_linktext,
      'menu' : page    
    }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

@decorator.oauth_required
def get(self):
    if decorator.has_credentials():          
        event_name = self.request.get('event-name')
        event = {  
         'summary': 'Appointment from get',  
         'location': 'Somewhere close to it',  
         'start': {    
                   'dateTime': '2013-04-15T10:00:00.000-07:00'  ,
                   'timeZone': 'America/New_York'
                   },  
         'end': {    
                 'dateTime': '2013-04-15T10:25:00.000-07:00',
                 'timeZone': 'America/New_York'  
                 },  
        }

        http = decorator.http()

        request = service.events().insert(calendarId='MyCalendarId', body=event)
        inserted = request.execute(http)

    else:
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps({'error': 'No credentials'}))

    page = 'main'
    template_values = {
      'url': url,
      'url_linktext': url_linktext,
      'menu' : page    
    }

    template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/index.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

The OAuth2 is used as follow:

```
decorator = OAuth2Decorator(
  client_id='client ID',
  client_secret='client secret',
  scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar')
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong here and why I am getting "Login Required" exception in one case and not in the other when both methods do pretty much the same thing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out how to resolve the problem.

I needed to change post() method to look something like this:

```
@decorator.oauth_aware    
def post(self):

if decorator.has_credentials():          
    #event_name = self.request.get('event-name')
    event = {  
     'summary': self.request.get('summary'),  
     'location': self.request.get('place'),  
     'status' : self.request.get('status'),
     'start': {    
               'dateTime': '2013-05-11T10:00:00.000-07:00'  ,
               'timeZone': 'America/New_York'
               },  
     'end': {    
             'dateTime': '2013-05-11T10:25:00.000-07:00',
             'timeZone': 'America/New_York'  
             },  
    }
    http = decorator.http()
    request = service.events().insert(calendarId='MyCalendarId', body=event).execute(http=http)
    :
    :
```

The solution is actually based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812813/oauth2-authentication-in-gae-accessing-calendar-api-v3-domain-hosted).