# Access Google Calendar within Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am new to Google App Engine (GAE) and its Python api. For the past weekend, I have been trying to set up a simple app that will send SMS message to my phone whenever it sees an upcoming event in the calendar. For that purpose, I am using GAE with Twilio and Google Calendar API (v3)--all in Python.

I have a GAE account and was able to run simple tutorial web app by following an example here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction and here https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/twilio. I was also able to run cron job to send SMS messages using Python scripts on GAE successfully. But when I am having trouble figuring out how to write a script (cron job) that will retrieve calendar events (of my GAE account) using Google Calendar API. I have read a bunch of tutorials and instructions on Google developer, but just found myself getting confused more and more.

- Is that possible to create a Python script for cron job to be run on GAE to retrieve calendar events? I came across [OAuth2 authentication in GAE accessing Calendar API V3 (domain hosted)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13812813/oauth2-authentication-in-gae-accessing-calendar-api-v3-domain-hosted) which is close to what I was trying to achieve, but not quite (my plan is not to create web app for users). Is the rumor true that Google Calendar API doesn't work with Service Accounts?
- Using OAuth 2.0 requires the user to allow access. What I understand is that it will return an access token to the requesting application for a certain period (1hr?) and then will require user to refresh or go through the granting-access-procedure again? If that's the case, I do not want to use it since my goal is to have a script that periodically runs (say every fifteen minutes) to see if there is any upcoming calendar event in next 15 minutes.
- If someone could direct me to an example Python script that will work on retrieving Google Calendar events from an owner's account on GAE, that would be greatly helpful.

If someone can answer any of the above questions, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Can't answer fully at the moment, but just wanted to mention that for your point 2 you've misunderstood refresh tokens: they don't require re-authentication or granting again, they just require the app to swap the refresh token for an access token, which it does automatically if you're using the recommended library (and you've configured your access for offline use).

Comment: Thanks, @DanielRoseman. When you find time, could you please answer my first and third question (or anything that you find will lead me to the right direction)? I have spent at least ten hour trying to read up and figure this out to no avail. I have read pretty much every Google-able stuff about this, but no one talks about how one might set up a script to retrieve calendar events (of the owner's account) on GAE. Thank you, again.